# Deep mapping with generics in Dozer

Tags: java, generics, mapping, dozer

I've been struggling with how to map to object with generics in Dozer and have not found anything to aid me after extensive searching.

I'm trying to map some objects that I wrote to some that were created by someone else. I started out using annotations and saw a similar error so I moved to using a mapping file instead. However, it doesn't seemed to have helped.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
public interface MyObject<T extends MyContent> {
   T getData();
}

public interface MyStaff extends MyContent {
   Demo getDemo();
}

public interface Demo {
   Name getName();
}

public interface Name {
  String getFirstName();
  String setFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

```xml
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.example.Staff</class-a>
    <class-b>com.example.MyObject</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>firstName</a>
        <b>data.demo.name.firstName</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field (data.demo.name.firstName) in class (interface com.example.MyObject)
```

I've tried another of permutations (using concrete classes rather than interfaces, for example) and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. It seems the issue was due to the fact that the implementation class was not public. It seems like this might be a bug or at least an enhancement. Dozer should either notify you the class isn't accessible as suggesting the field isn't found is misleading.